# How to create generic rdlc templates with dynamic data tables generated at run time?

Tags: c#, .net, dynamic, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I have an `rdlc` report in my solution.
I want to set the report `datasource` with run-time generated data table.
How can I do that?

I haven't used any xsd file to design the report.
I just want to display the data table from the database on the report.

Answer (score 0):

[Try this link.](http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/13169999-ef3b-496c-b502-caef973c3bb2/Using%20ReportViewer%20in%20WinForms%20C)

In the link you will see a class is added to the application and it is used as DataSource. You can add as many data sources as you want. You can also add more than one DataSource in one RDLC report.